# Jmeter Using regex in Groovy to find a substring

Tags: groovy, jmeter

in Jmeter I am using JSR223PostProcessor with Groovy, the HTTP response is a JSON Block something like this:

```
{
  "A1": 283,
  "XYZ": "123@192.168.12.12",
  "A3": "",
  "A4": {
  "A6": 1,
 }
}
```

I am interested in searching for-->

```
"XYZ": "*@*",
```

I may or may NOT have that line and note the * can be anything
Currently I am doing this and it works:

```
if (response.contains("@"))
```

but I like a more elegant way -->

```
"XYZ":{any white space}"{any set of digits}@{anychars}",
```

how can I do it in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need regular expressions here, I would rather recommend going for [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and just rely on `XYZ` attribute presence, the relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
def xyz = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).XYZ
if (xyz == null) {
    log.info('XYZ string was not found')
}
else {
    log.info('XYZ value is: ' + xyz)
}
```

- In case if string is not present you will get `not found` message:

  [image: JMeter Groovy JSON Not Found]

  - In case if string is present you will get its value:

    [image: JMeter Groovy JSON Found]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Sorry .. I should have been more clear, I can have another condition where I have XYZ like this:   "XYZ": "123",
I need to be careful NOT To include that in my finding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators):

```
def response = prev.responseDataAsString

if ( response =~ /"XYZ":\s*"\d*@.*"/ ) {
    println "found it!"
}
```

Comment: Hi Ian : if ( response =~ /"XYZ":\s*"\d*@.*"/ ) {   did not work.  I tried my old way again and it found it:

Comment: I assumed that `response` is the entire JSON response as a `String`. I think you'd have to use `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` to get that.

Comment: @user3556956 glad to hear that. if you would mark this as the correct answer it would be much appreciated.